# Считывание нажатия стрелок С++ Linux Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

Пишу консольную игру 2048 и столкнулся с проблемой отсутствия стандартных функций С++ считывания нажатий на стелки на клавиатуре. getch() не работает, ибо не поддерживается. Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть варианты?
(в будущем будет использоваться как часть свич-кейса)

Comment: *getch() не работает, ибо не поддерживается.* - правда? А *ncurses* про это знает? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int getch()
{
    struct termios oldattr, newattr;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldattr );
    newattr = oldattr;
    newattr.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newattr );
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldattr );
    return ch;
}
```

Имхо, самый простой вариант - это свой гетч без мам пап и установки ncurses.

Comment: Не очень-то эффективно на каждый символ делать 3 вызова termios. Можно ведь сделать это один раз в начале (и в конце (ну, в середине работы, если требуется смена режима, то в отдельной функции).  Выполнение в конце  можно и автоматизировать по atexit (дело вкуса).

Answer (score 4):

Для POSIX систем стандартной библиотекой для работы с терминалом является `curses`, и в частности её GNU'тая реализация `ncurses`. Вот небольшой Hello world, как получать ввод с помощью стрелок:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {

    unsigned x=0, y=0;
    int ch;

    initscr ();
    keypad (stdscr, 1);

    do {
        mvprintw(y, x, "Hello World !!!");
        refresh();
        ch = getch();
        mvprintw(y, x, "               ");
        switch (ch) {
            case KEY_UP   :  y--; y %= LINES; break;
            case KEY_DOWN :  y++; y %= LINES; break;
            case KEY_LEFT :  x--; x %= COLS ; break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:  x++; x %= COLS ; break;
        }
    } while (ch != 'q');

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Компилировать с помощью `gcc -lncurses move.c -o move`. Само собой, библиотека (n)curses и хедеры должны быть установлены (обычно это пакеты `ncurses` и `ncurses-dev`). Выход по <kbd>q</kbd>.

Из ключевых моментов — вызов `keypad ()`, который переводит библиотеку в режим интерпретации ввода функциональных клавиш «по одной за раз».

Предлагаемое дальнейшее чтение [Ncurses Programming HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)

Answer (score 3):

Нужно в консоли отключать автоматическое эхо и всю дребедень. Потом вернуть всё назад.

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iso646.h>
int main(){
  int fd = STDIN_FILENO ;
  FILE* fp = stdin ;
  FILE* fo = stdout ;
  struct termios termios_p ;
  struct termios termios_pold ;
  if( tcgetattr(fd, &termios_p)) return 1;
  termios_pold = termios_p ;

  //cfmakeraw(&termios_p);
  termios_p.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP
                           | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
  termios_p.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
  termios_p.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
  termios_p.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
  termios_p.c_cflag |= CS8;

  if( tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW,&termios_p)) return 2;
  for(int i = 100;i>0;--i){
    int c = fgetc(fp);
    if(fprintf(stdout,"c=%c(%d)\n\r",c,c)<0) return 2;}
  if( tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW,&termios_pold)) return 3;
  return 0;}
```

Comment: Лучше, возможно, не колдовать самому с терминалом, а воспользоваться ncurses.